# Microsoft Teams image upload: "Something went wrong while sharing. Let's try again."

Tags: upload, microsoft-teams

I'm attempting to send a small image via the Microsoft Teams desktop application.

```
Attach Files > Upload from this Device
```

But "something goes wrong with sharing":

[image: Microsoft Teams: Something went wrong while sharing. Let's try again.]

> Something went wrong while sharing. Let's try again.

Why can't I upload/share images in the Microsoft Teams desktop app?

Comment: Besides the outage, is this a business environment? Is OneDrive enabled in the tenant or for you?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft cloud services (365, Teams, etc) have been experiencing problems for much of the day today.  Our users are also submitting tickets about problems like what you've posted:

https://downdetector.com/status/teams/

Sadly, this may be one of those "shrug and wait for it to go away" problems.